# FCM recurring notification not work on second day

Tags: react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have implemented the FCM in my react native app and it works perfectly with instant and schedule notification.

However, when I create a recurring notification in FCM console, the notification only able to send on the first time but not the second time and after it.

For example, the recurring notification start on today, 12.00PM and it should be repeat every day 12.00PM. Yes, today 12.00 PM the notification sent and recevied by the device. But on second day and the day after it, the notification not sent and not received by the device.

Could some help me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should change the scheduling option like this picture, in the custom option, u can use every 1 day and don't use daily option
[image: custom option]

Comment: Thanks! I think I know how to do now.

Comment: Hi, Please @JYY could you explain how have you can resolve this? I have the same issue, I have tried to put the recurrents messages for weeks, days… but always send correctly the first message but no the second…